# Can anyone explain why p and p2 have the same mem address?

Tags: c++, virtual, dynamic-cast

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class B
{
    int i;

public:
    B() { i = 1; }
    virtual int get_i() { return i; }
};
class D : virtual public B
{
    int j;

public:
    D() { }
};
class D2 : virtual public B
{
    int j2;

public:
    D2() {}
};
class MM : public D, public D2
{
    int x;

public:
    MM() {  }
};
int main()
{
    B* o = new MM();
    MM* p = dynamic_cast<MM*>(o);
    D* p2 = dynamic_cast<D*>(o);
    return 0;
}
```

I thought `p` and `p2` will have the address of `o` since the casts are successful.

I dont understand why `p` and `p2` have the same memory address.

Can anyone explain me why?

Comment: Better question: why do you care that they have the same address?

Comment: i want to understand properly

Comment: Why do you expect that the address stored in `p` and `p2` should be different?

Comment: Understand what, exactly? This is just a choice made by this specific compiler version on a specific platform. It could be radically different on another combination.

Comment: If you reverse the order of D and D2 in the inheritance list of MM you'll probably see the addresses are different. That will help you understand what your compiler has chosen to do.

Comment: I think this is a valid question with proper example, no need to be so dismissive here.

Comment: "I tought they have the same address (the same as `o`), but I dont understand why they have the same adress" is there a "not" missing somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Sub objects of an enclosing object are stored at various offsets from the start of The enclosing object. The first sub object is stored at offset 0 and it had the same memory address as the enclosing object.

The base sub object D pointed by p is a sub object of MM pinted by p2. If it happens to be the first sub object, then the address is same.

Another common example of this that you may encounter is that first element of an array has the same memory address as the array itself. Array elements are sub objects.

Comment: but p address != o address

Comment: @ionescuradu why would the address need to change? The way that compiler has implemented it there is no need for a dynamic vtable because you're never overriding `get_i`

Comment: one last question, why address(o) != address(p)?

Comment: @eerorika Is inheritance actually *an enclosing object*? Doesn't the whole virtual thing throw things off and it's just chance that `p` and `p2` end up with the same address, i.e. offset 0 inside `MM`? https://godbolt.org/z/qacWPx81T gives: o  = 0x1ee7ed0, mm = 0x1ee7eb0, d  = 0x1ee7eb0, d2 = 0x1ee7ec0. The `B` inside `MM` is not at offset 0 despide being a subobject of `D`.